# How do test Smart TV Alliance SDK app on actual Device

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I've been playing with the Smart TV Alliance SDK and have built an app which runs fine on the emulator but I need to test and demo it on an actual device before I continue with the project.

I have purchased an LG TV with the latest firmware and need to package or display somehow through the TV but no documentation exists to walk through packaging to device.

Does anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 1):

On TV:

1. Open Smart TV homepage - Click on 'More' - Sign in with credentials.
2. Insert USB with predefined directory stucture containing the DRM'ed package downloaded from LG developer website

With computer:
More information on how to create the DRM'ed package:

a. Go to http://developer.lge.com/
b. Login in with credentials

Select: Resource center - Smart TV
Select: Test - App test
Select: New app test (fill in information, app type is: Web - Hosted)

Download DRM'ed content in .zip.

Create USB structure:

create "lgapps" directory at root of USB
create "installed" directory under "lgapps" directory.
    ( USB root > lgapps > installed)
extract directory from DRM'ed file and copy it under the 'installed' directory.

This is complete, for further assistence please consult the FAQ section.

The Smart TV Alliance SDK respects the Smart TV Alliance Specification fully. For more information visit http://www.smarttv-alliance.org/.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some guidelines. You can find them here:

https://github.com/ruiposse/smart-tv-app-dev-guidelines#testing

> First, use the "Export App Test" option in the LG IDE. Then, update
>   the package to the "App Test" option in the LG Developer site and
>   download the DRM applied file. You create lgapps/installed/{appid}
>   folder structure inside a usb stick, unzip the downloaded file into it
>   and insert the usb stick into the LG TV.
>
> When you upload the web app into the LG Developer site, you have to
>   insert an URL in the form. This is really good, because it means that
>   you don't have to go over this process every time you change something
>   in your app.
>
> So, I just create and upload a package that allows the TV to connect
>   to my web server. After that I can continue/start to code the app and
>   instantly test on the real device by reloading the TV app.
>
> It's always good to read the [official documentation about
>   deployment](http://developer.lgappstv.com/TV_HELP/index.jsp?topic=/lge.tvsdk.testing.book/html/RealTV/Deploying%20and%20Testing%20App%20on%20Real%20TV/Deploying%20and%20Testing%20App%20on%20Real%20TV.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Every TV vendor has different way how to create and install the application - Samsung, LG, Toshiba, Sony (SEN), Opera TV, Philips and Panasonic. You can find some smart TV related information here - [www.mautilus.com/blog](http://www.mautilus.com/blog). If you have some question regarding some specific TV let me know.

STeN