# Packaging and testing the app in smart tv

Tags: smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I am creating the app for LG and panasonic smart tv's using smart tv alliance sdk. How can i package and test the app in the real tv.

Comment: has answer about LG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789132/how-do-test-smart-tv-alliance-sdk-app-on-actual-device

Comment: I saw that but they mentioned using LG SDK. I am using smart tv alliance SDK. @Ivan Solntsev

Comment: to test on LG device you need account on LG dev site. as far as I know, Alliance SDK do not provide way to test applications on real devices

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know how i can package my app  using Alliance sdk

Comment: I don`t used Alliance SDK, so I don`t know. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Application deployment is vendor specific – i.e. Philips, Toshiba and LGE have different  ways how they publish the application, they have different requirements for e.g. metadata, icon sizes, ways how to publish to for more countries, etc.

The certification for STA is described quite well on their web page http://www.smarttv-alliance.org/

BR
STeN